# How to set the receiver

Tags: javascript, oop, function, receiver

How can I rewrite a function that is in the form:

```
 foo = function(arg1,arg2){....};
```

into a form such that `arg1` becomes the receiver, to be used like the following?

```
arg1.foo(arg2);
```

---

**Edit**
I found out that with jQuery, I can do this.

```
jQuery.fn.foo = function(arg){
  ...
}
```

What is the way to do this with Javascript not using jQuery?

Comment: The function `foo` would have to be in the `arg1` object. Meaning `arg1` would need to be an instance of your class that holds the `foo` function.

Comment: For future folks (like I was, until I became a past peon), the requirement that `arg1` be a `DOMElement` may be useful to know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects that jQuery returns are jQuery objects, not DOM objects. They *contain* collections of DOM objects, but jQuery does not directly add any methods to DOM objects at all. `jQuery.fn` is simply a reference to the prototype of the objects returned by jQuery, allowing you to add methods to that prototype directly.

Since you're interested in reproducing jQuery's behavior, you could do the same: wrap native DOM objects in a class of your own, adding whatever methods you want to that wrapper class. Note that you cannot call just any DOM object method on a jQuery instance; jQuery defines some utility methods for invoking actual DOM methods, but in order to call many other DOM methods, you need to access the real DOM objects wrapped inside the jQuery instance. You will have the same limitation with your custom wrapper class — you will need to implement methods on your wrapper that forward the call to the underlying DOM object.

Example:

```
function DOMWrapper(domObject) {
    this.domObject = domObject;
}

DOMWrapper.prototype = {

    constructor: DOMWrapper,

    foo: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        // this.domObject refers to the wrapped object here
        this.domObject.nativeMethod();
        // you could do things like this here:
        return this.bar.call(this.domObject, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    },

    bar: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        // now, even though "bar" is defined as a method of
        // the DOMWrapper prototype, it has been invoked by "foo"
        // in the context of the wrapped DOM object, so
        // "this" refers directly to the DOM object in this method

        // this goes to the actual DOM nativeMethod:
        return this.nativeMethod();
    },

    domMethodWrapper: function() {
        return this.domObject.nativeMethod();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

Directly attach a function to each element. (more compatible)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/tE6gf/

jsFiddle's *slow* today so here's a [JS Bin mirror](http://jsbin.com/uxoniv/2/)

JavaScript:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("elm");

elm.foo = function(arg) {
    alert(arg.arg1); // What I thought you might've meant :D
};

elm.foo({
    arg1: "Arg 1 Value",
    arg2: "Arg 2 Value",
    arg3: "Arg 3 Value",
    arg4: "Arg 5 Value"
});

var arg1 = document.getElementById("div2");

// To match your example
arg1.foo = function(arg1, arg2){ alert(arg1); };

var arg2 = "This is a random string";

arg1.foo(arg2);
```

### Solution 2

Extend `Element.prototype`. (only backwards compatible to IE 7)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/8W2Nx/

JavaScript:

```
Element.prototype.foo = function(arg1, arg2) {
    alert(arg1);
};

document.getElementById("test").foo("String 1");​
```

Comment: In order to do that you have to define the function on the object every time you create a dom object.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, you want to create jQuery-like syntax for _all_ elements without creating a library or initiating one?

Comment: You could do it [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/vR9Yu/) way, but I don't know any of the consequences of modifying every single element on a page.

Comment: The above script is plenty fast, as you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/vR9Yu/1/) demo, it takes about 5ms to extend 1000 elements.

Comment: @sawa I just added another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var arg1 = { 
    foo: function(arg2) { } 
};

arg1.foo(arg2)
```

**Update**

You should just be able to add the function onto the object:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');

test.foo = function(arg) {
    alert(this.innerHTML + " : " + arg);
};

test.foo("Hello");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJSDS/

Comment: I already have a DOM object `arg1`, and cannot change that to something else. How can I define that to all DOM objects?

Comment: @sawa Where do you get the object from?

Comment: @sawa I don't think all browsers support extending the DOM prototype ([how Prototype does it](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/extensions), [DOM prototype in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript-DOM_Prototypes_in_Mozilla), [before IE8 you can't access it for sure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd282900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#domproto))

Comment: @RichardD I get it through `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

define the function you want to use:

```
function original_foo(color) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

then walk through all the dom nodes and attach the function as a method:

```
var all_nodes = document.querySelectorAll("*");
for (var i in all_nodes) {
    var node = all_nodes[i];
    node.foo = original_foo;
}
```

now call the method:

```
var d = document.getElementById("d2");
d.foo("red");

document.getElementById("d1").foo("green");
```

See this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/G9e9C/

Answer (score -3):

You can resolve it this way:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
   if (typeof arg1 == 'function')
      arg1(arg2); // or 'return arg1(arg2)' if necessary
   else
      return false;
}
```

You can easily test it with:

```
foo(alert,'hello world');
```